# .htaccess redirect if url ends with certain extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to do a redirect if the url ends in `.asp` to just 301 to the same url but with just `/`

So for example I would like

`domain.com/category/thingy.asp` to redirect to `domain.com/category/thingy/`

Some urls have .asp others don't.

I understand this part of it

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .asp` but not sure what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)\.asp$ /$1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that works on wordpress, you can make it using PHP like

```
$currentUrl = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
if(strpos($currentUrl, ".asp")) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    $currentUrl = str_replace(".asp", "/", $currentUrl);
    header("Location:". $currentUrl);
    die();
}
```